# AJAX Multiple File Upload - Identifying original element?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Assuming multiple upload input types exist on a HTML page, I want to be able to obtain the `name` attribute of each file upload that is submit with a file, this way the PHP server-side can determine exactly what file uploader is passing what file.

**My Code:**

```js
$('.php-email-form').submit(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  var form = $(this);
  var data = new FormData();
  
  // add datas of input not file to data object
  $.each($(':input', form).not(':input[type=submit]'), function(i, fields){
    data.append($(fields).attr('name'), $(fields).val());
    console.log($(fields).attr('name'), $(fields).val());
  });    
  
  // add data from inputs type file
  $.each($('input[type=file]', form)[0].files, function (i, file) {
    data.append(file.name, file);
    console.log(file.name);
    console.log($(this).attr('name')); // test, trying to get the name attribute of input type file
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="php-email-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="test" value="value"><br>
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="photo" name="photo"><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

When I look at the `$_FILES` array in PHP, I get the following output:

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "value" }

array(1) { ["IMG_8085_JPG"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_8085.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpxsP6RN" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(65949) } }
```

As seen above, the index of the above image is the image name *(IMG_8085_JPG)* though I want this index to be the name of the original input it came from. *(Either photo or photo-2)*

So if an image was uploaded in the `photo` element, the array should look like the following:

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "value" }

array(1) { ["photo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_8085.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpxsP6RN" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(65949) } }
```

It seems that the `name` index is overwritten on the elements when a file is uploaded, so `$(this).attr("name")` no longer references the attribute but rather becomes the name of the file that is uploaded.

I post all my jQuery code below :

```js
$('.php-email-form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var form = $(this);     
    var formAction = $(form).attr('action');
    var data = new FormData();

    // add data from inputs type text
    $.each($(':input', form).not(':input[type=submit]'), function(i, fields){
      data.append($(fields).attr('name'), $(fields).val());
    });    

    // add data from inputs type file
    $.each($('input[type=file]', form)[0].files, function (i, file) {
      data.append(file.name, file);
      console.log(file);
      console.log($(this).attr('name'));
    });

    $('.loading').fadeIn();

    $.ajax({
      url: formAction,
      type: "POST",
      data: data,
      contentType: false,
      cache: false,
      processData: false,
    }).done(function(data){
      $('.loading').hide();
      $('.sent-message').fadeIn().html(data);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      $('.loading').hide();
      $('.error-message').show().html(errorThrown);
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The result i expect when i var_dump $_POST & $_FILES :

```
array(1) { ["test"]=> string(5) "value" }


array(1) { ["photo"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(12) "IMG_8085.JPG" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpxsP6RN" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(65949) } }
```

Comment: What do you mean by name of the input? Do you mean you just want what type the upload is, in this case "image/jpeg"?

Comment: I want this array but named with the input name attribute

Comment: Can you give an example of how you want the array to look? I don't understand what you mean by wanting the input name attribute. Do you mean you just want the array index to be named 'photo'?

Comment: Yes, i edited my post with the array i expect

Comment: IT looks like you're displaying the output in PHP, can you show your PHP code that is giving you your output for the array?

Comment: i just output : var_dump($_FILES)

Comment: What PHP version are you using? I have just tested the same and my array is created with the index of 'photo' when I `var_dump` the `$_FILES` variable. https://i.imgur.com/Vat2d8j.png

Comment: Version : 5.6.40. Check my snippet plz, you will see what you get

Comment: I see the snippet, but that is only showing result from jQuery which is giving the file name. You want to have the 'photos' index in PHP when you get the file on the server, correct?

Comment: Yes but i get this answer from my php file in the array $_FILES

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229553/discussion-between-skully-and-the-death-raw).

Comment: I edited my code a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating through each input's file directly instead of the element itself, this makes the type attribute accessible.

```js
$.each($('input[type=file]', form), function(i, file) { // Iterate through every file upload element.
    let uploadedFile = this.files[0]; // Get the file that was uploaded to this input.
    data.append(this.name, uploadedFile); // Append it to the form data under the index of the name of the input it was provided in.

    // Testing.
    console.log(this.name); // input name (in this case, 'photo')
    console.log(uploadedFile); // uploaded file element object.
});
```

The difference here is that when you are iterating through `('input[type=file]', form)[0].files`, you are accessing the files directly and the parent input that they are coming from aren't accessible because there is no reference to them.

The solution is to iterate through every input with the type of 'file' so we still fetch every input and have access to the 'name' attribute, we can then fetch the file itself that was uploaded within the loop with `this.files[0]`. *(Gets the first file uploaded.)*

Comment: Thank you for your help but i get Internal Server Error with your code

Comment: Are you still experiencing this error? I have tested the code again and it runs perfectly fine, are you sure it isn't an internal error on your end?

Comment: I fixed the problem in my php file. Thank you for everything

Answer (score 1):

The main thing missing in the code is `enctype` attribute for the form. Whenever you use a file input in a form, you must specify the enctype as `multipart/form-data`.

Change your form tag to:

```
<form class="php-email-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Now you can send the form as simple as (no need to assign values manually)

```
$('.php-email-form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var myFormData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test-dest.php',
        data: myFormData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

and echo the $_FILES from the test-dest.php using

```
echo var_dump($_FILES);
```

This will give you the result in

```
    array(1) {
  ["photo"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "web-design.png"
    ["type"]=>
    string(9) "image/png"
    ["tmp_name"]=>
    string(25) "D:\myfolder\tmp\phpC00E.tmp"
    ["error"]=>
    int(0)
    ["size"]=>
    int(4001)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but i get error when i try your code

Comment: Can you please share the error here? I have executed the code without any errors. @The_Death_Raw

Comment: [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 90ms]

Comment: Can you please show your test-dest.php code? The internal server most probably occurs there.

Comment: I fixed the problem in my php file. The answer of Skully and yours works, but i validate the answer of Skully because he was the first one to answer. Thank you for your help :)